# Network request failed in react-native expo problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to get data from local server but i am failure to connect local server.I am facing
"Network request failed"

```
     const testScreen= async ()=> {
            await fetch("http://192.168.56.1:3000/comments")
            .then((response)=>{
                console.log(response.json())
            })

            .catch((error)=>{
                console.log("sorry")
                console.log(error)
            })
    }

...error..

    Network request failed
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:535:17 in setTimeout$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:130:14 in _callTimer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:383:16 in callTimers
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
at [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: open http://192.168.56.1:3000/comments in browser and see if server is reachable or not.

Comment: Needs more detail, maybe you are facing CORS issue where you are accessing the API across the domain between `localhost` and specified IP server

Comment: i am using firefox.when i run the application in web no CORS problem found and data found.But in mobile expo again show "Network Error
"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the server is running and that is on port 3000.
In addition change the "testScreen" function to be like this:

```
const testScreen = () => {
        fetch("http://192.168.56.1:3000/comments")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            console.log("sorry")
            console.log(error)
        })
}
```

Comment: I have tried but again same problem.."Network request failed
"

Answer (score 0):

This is may related to CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue. Enable CORS in your server side code.

Apart from the fetch method you can use some other libraries like axios.

```
axios.get('http://192.168.56.1:3000/comments')
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Network Error
at node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:14 in createError

Comment: Have you enabled CORS in your server side ?